# How does CLR differentiate classes with the same name but without namespace in different assemblies at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

How does CLR differentiate classes with the same name but without namespace in different assemblies at runtime?

Example :

Assembly : Assembly1

```
public class Foo
{
    public void Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Assembly 1 class Foo");
    }
}
```

Please note class Foo is not having any namespace.

Assembly : Assembly2

```
public class Foo
{
    public void Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Assembly 2 class Foo");
    }
}
```

Please note class Foo is not having any namespace here too.

So Assembly1 and Assembly2 are having classes with the same name but without namespace.

Assembly : TestAssembly1 ---->Refers : Assembly1

```
namespace TestAssembly1 
{
    public class TestAssembly1Class
    {
        public void CallFooMethod()
        {
            new Foo().Test();   //How CLR would know this Foo is from Assembly 1 at runtime?
        }
    }
}
```

Assembly : TestAssembly2---------->Refers : Assembly2

```
namespace TestAssembly2 
{
    public class TestAssembly2Class
    {
        public void CallFooMethod()
        {
            new Foo().Test();   //How CLR would know this Foo is from Assembly 2 at runtime?
        }
    }
}
```

Now suppose There is one Executable say MyShell.exe which has Main method. which looks like following.

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new TestAssembly1Class().CallFooMethod();
            new TestAssembly2Class().CallFooMethod();
        }
    }
```

So here question is that, both Foo classes are not having any namespace then, when MyShell.exe is executed how CLR will differentiate these conflicting Foo classes?

Comment: Just like you can differentiate two `new object()`'s from each other - although the types have the same name, they are different objects in the memory space of the CLR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does CLR differentiate classes with the same name but without
>   namespace in different assemblies at runtime?

Both types would have a different [`AssemblyQualifiedName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Because when the two assemblies are compiled independently prior to inclusion and the two types are each assigned a fully qualified name which includes the assembly name.

When the third assembly, which references the two previous assemblies, is compiled and names are bound the *conflict* is resolved via the fully qualified name.